# Google Drive Permissions

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I work for an un-launched startup that handles a large amount of user media. We are looking to integrate Google Drive as a way for a user to store that media.

Is it possible to have read/write access to a user's Google Drive, after obtaining their permission via OAUTH2? More specifically the ability to create folders on their drive and access them for read/write scenarios.

We would also need to be able to generate direct links to their photos, videos, etc.

We've successfully integrated with Dropbox in this manner and would like to offer Google Drive as an alternative. Are these scenarios possible with Google Drive?

Comment: Google Drive and Google Cloud Storage are two completely different products. For Drive, the answer is 'yes'

Comment: Please read both api docs first and ask a specific question about them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.

You will want to read about our [Auth Scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes) and determine what the minimal set of scopes are that you need to operate. As an example, drive.file scope will enable you to create files & folders, read them, as well as read/write any existing files that a user explicitly opens with your application.

The 'explicitly open' part can be handled in 2 ways. You can register an 'Open' action for your app in the Drive UI for certain file types and you can use our 'File Picker' widget in your app to enable the user to select which files to open/grant access. You can read about [opening files in our docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open)

Comment: First link is broken - is it now this one?  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Comment: Urgh, it appears to have broken with the v3 docs launch. For link is: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes